# CruiseControl select parameters using from plugin

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

It's hard to find information regarding CruiseControl development, so I hope somebody knows it here...

I have developed plugins for CruiseControl.NET (inmplementing `ITask`) and faced a problems with parameters. I made a workarounds for both, but I'll do appreciate if you suggest other solutions. So...

1. When parameters are used in properties passed to plugins, they are simply not substituted. I mean that having `<someProperty>$[SomeParameter]</someProperty>`, plugin receives `someProperty = "$[SomeParameter]"`, not it's value. The workaround I had to make is manually replacing the placeholders using `IIntegrationResult.Parameters` in code.
2. When using select parameters, the values in `IIntegrationResult.Parameters` are actually names! So having select parametes with `<value name="Name">Value</value>`, it looks like no way to get "Value" from plugin - all I get is "Name" in `IIntegrationResult.Parameters`. I had to make a workaround by using the same names as values, but this is not convenient to use, because the values are quite long and differ only in the ends.

Please suggest, am I missing something?